# Creating a temporary tab without adding it to history or sessions in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a tab that should be temporary and shouldn't show up in history or recently closed tabs; I can't use popups for this because of [Chrome bug 436489](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=436489), because the tab needs to be opened programmatically. I also can't use content scripts, since that would exclude `chrome://` tabs. I've tried to remove the temporary tab from history like this:

`chrome.history.onVisited.addListener(({url}) => {
  if (url.startsWith(temporary))
    chrome.history.deleteUrl({url})
})`

But it doesn't work because of [Chrome bug 395955](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395955), and even if it worked, it would still be saved in `chrome.sessions`, and there's no API to remove it from there. Is there no other way to create a temporary page in Chrome that could be opened and closed programmatically?

Comment: You could open the tab in an incognito window. That seems too simple though, so I guess asking users to enable the extension in incognito windows is not an option for you.

Comment: Sadly, no; the tab is a tab switcher, so it needs to be in the same window.

Comment: Hmmm... a tab swicher. Does this mean that the page that you want to open on the temporary tab is a local page included with your extension?

Comment: Yes, it's an extension page.